# fxFlex not resizing elements

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

fxFlex directive not working on width, however when I manually set a width it works, how can I make it work?

I have tried making the mat-card element width 100% in the styles.scss file but that takes all of the space available in the div

The div grabs all the available space

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFill>

    <mat-card fxFlex.lt-sm="90" fxFlex.lt-md="80"  fxFlex="70">
        <mat-card-title>Create a new user</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>

        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

I get this
[image: got this]

But I want this using only directives
[image: expected]

Comment: not sure exactly what you're asking here; what end result do you want? the `div` to take 100% width? You may want to try using `fxLayout="row"` instead of "column"

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try using fxLayout="row" instead of "column".